# is it possible to dynamically change the url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a page where books are to be display either with "grid" view or with "list" view.

So my current url is 
   `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/8`

and if i click on "list" link from my view page then my current page should load with only changing this part `/grid/` to `/list/` and other same.
    i.e `http://localhost/thebestbookfinder.com/viewallbooks/books/pgn/list/8`

I tried this but this is not helpful. Please help me to solve this issue.

inMyViewPage.php

```
<td width="10%" style="font-size:12px;color: red;"> 
       <?php
                                       echo "".anchor('#', 'Grid', array('id' => '')).""; 
                                       echo "".anchor(base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/'.$this->uri->segment(4),'  List', array('id' => ''))."";
                                        ?>
                                    </td>
```

**Instead of link if form submition solve my problem then please help me with that**

Controller.php

```
 function books()
{
    $config = array();  
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/'.$this->uri->segment(4); 
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count_for_secondtopBooks('3');
    $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
    $config['per_page'] = 8;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>'; 

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;

    $data["query"] = $this->Subjectmodel->get_subjects();
    $data["query1"]=  $this->Editionmodel->get_edition();





    $data["query2"]=$this->Booksmodel->get_all_book_list_atHomeTop('3',$config["per_page"], $page);


    $viewType = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 'list';

     if($viewType=='list')
     {
          $this->load->view('commonfiles/bookslistview',$data);

     }
      else {
                  $this->load->view('commonfiles/booksgridview',$data);  
          }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this one:

```
 <?php  echo "".anchor(base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/grid/'.$this->uri->segment(5),'  Grid', array('id' => ''))."";
  echo "".anchor(base_url().'viewallbooks/books/pgn/list/'.$this->uri->segment(5),'  List', array('id' => ''))."";  ?>
```

And no need to change anything in above controller.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add route in route.php like this

```
$route['viewallbooks/books/(:any)'] = "viewallbooks/books/$1";
```

Function books() shold contain 3 params with values by default
Below is more correct varian

```
    function books($img_type = 'png', $view_type = 'list', $page = 0) {
            $config = array();  
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'viewallbooks/books/'.$img_type.'/'.$view_type.'/'.$page; 
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->Booksmodel->record_count_for_secondtopBooks('3');
            $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
            $config['per_page'] = 8;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>'; 

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            $data["query"] = $this->Subjectmodel->get_subjects();
            $data["query1"]= $this->Editionmodel->get_edition();
            $data["query2"]= $this->Booksmodel->get_all_book_list_atHomeTop('3',$config["per_page"], $page);

            if($viewType=='list')
                $this->load->view('commonfiles/bookslistview',$data);
            else
                $this->load->view('commonfiles/booksgridview',$data);
        }
```

Comment: i have not tried this. But  Mr Ashutosh answer, working fine only by keeping few lines in view page.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do either:

- Reload the page with the new url (grid) to render that template

OR:

- Render both the grid and list view and then dynamically (with some css/javascript) hide content based on what you'll want to see.

OR:

- Load the grid-view with AJAX and replacing the list with it.